# Port 25 (smtp) connection timed out

Tags: smtp

I created a postfix smtp server, earlier today it was working but now i can't connect to it. It gives me a "connection timed out" error. Even those online smtp checkers work. My friend also says he can't connect. I am running this in a cloud vm ubuntu 20.04

Comment: oh, i just realized that i can't even connect to port 25 on GMAIL's smtp server...

Comment: Is this an AWS instance / cloud VM?  Amazon blocks port 25 on their instances because of heavy abuse of AWS for sending spam as mail servers - you have to contact Amazon and have ample justification for the AWS server to have email functionality, and you even have to detail security measures, etc. to protect the server.

Comment: my cloud vm works fine, but my own computer, not so much

Comment: i'm confused, you're saying that your connection and your friend's connection can't reach to your Cloud VM?  It's unclear the exact problem you're having - i.e. what are you trying to do, from where, and what are the exact results you're seeing?